# Do I need more than one database tables if I want to have an image that is accompanied by other images?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Users will be able to upload 1 or as many images as they want using multiple image input.

```
Images table
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, file_name
```

The home will display the images but not display the accompanying images, they will be displayed on the specific image page. If the user uploads 1 image, there won't be accompanying images.

Home page would be something like this:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <a href='{{url("image/".$image->id)}}'>
        <img src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/thumbnails/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image'/>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

For simplicity, in the case of multiple images upload the first image in the array will be the main image that will be displayed on `home.blade.php` and will be saved in `file_name` column in `images` table.

On the specific image page, if the image does not have any accompanying images it should only have 1 image like this:

```
<img src='{{url("storage/uploads/images/specificImages/".$image->file_name)}}' alt='Random image' />
```

and if it has accompanying images it should display the main image and then the accompanying images.

Now my question is whether I should create a second table and model for the accompanying images or should I add a field in `images` table like `collection` that will contain an unique value that will be shared between images from same collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now my question is whether I should create a second table and model for the accompanying images or

It should be perfectly sufficient to add new column to existing table named i.e. `parent_id` and set its value for all accompanying images to `id` of the image they accompany (1st one from your set). And for that parent image's record, you keep that field set i.e. to `NULL` to indicate this one has no parent.

Comment: This. It's a self-reference. Just beware of cascade deleting